# decorator still calls function after failing

Tags: discord.py, python-decorators

I understand why the error check is printed, but I don't understand why despite the fact that the user calling does not have the mod label, it runs the function anyway, maybe I don't really understand decorators (user also has a token role but I commented that part out for this test)

```
# token check
@bot.command(name='wallet', help='display if a token is available for user')
@commands.has_role('mod') # remove later
# @commands.has_any_role('PBToken 3', 'PBToken 6')
async def token_check(ctx):
    name = ctx.author.name

    response = name + ', You have a token available!'
    
    await ctx.send(response)

# error message if user has no token currently
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.errors.MissingRole):
        name = ctx.author.name

        # await ctx.send(name + ', you currently do not have a token, keep leveling up!')
        await ctx.send('error check')
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Intead of using the mod role, why don't you run it using the check for whether the user has server administrator. To do that, all you do would be to replace:

```
@commands.has_role('mod')
```

with:

```
@commands.has_guild_permissions(administrator=True)
```

This would make the command only run if the specified user has server admin.
Please feel free to reply if you need any more help! :)

Comment: I did have this actually, but it too did not prevent the function from running :(

But in either case, the test account was neither a mod nor administrator so I don't know why I keep seeing "you have a token.." when I call the function ;s

Comment: Hmm, let me see.